# Intuitive explanation for covariance and inverse covariance

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, covariance, distance

Say we are given n observations from the same multidimensional distribution $D$.
I am trying to understand what is the intuition behind the following norms:

$\sqrt{x^TC_nx}$ and $\sqrt{x^TC_n^{-1}x}$

Where $C_n$ is the covariance matrix  of the $n$ observations.
What is the meaning of "close" in those norms?

Thanks